# Storing Date in NSUserDefaults Throwing Exception

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am comparing date1 to date2 with a small bit of code, and am getting a crash notification.

**I get date1 in NSUserDefaults with this:**

```
NSDate *date1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
objectForKey:@"date1"];

NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 

if (fabs([date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]) < 60)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"60 seconds or less" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

**I am storing date1 in NSUserDefaults like this:**

```
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date1 forKey:@"date1"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The app is crashing saying that -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: The error stated the the `date2` variable is not a date but a string. Did you post all your code, because it looks like you are setting a `NSString` to the `date2` variable and not an `NSDate`

Comment: That is not true. The error is in timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate which is called from timeIntervalSinceDate when 1 of the 2 dates is incorrect. So I think it is the date1 that is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have compiled your code and it works for me. This is how it looks:

```
NSDate *date1test = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date1test forKey:@"date1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


NSDate *date1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                 objectForKey:@"date1"];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
if (fabs([date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]) < 60)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"60 seconds or less" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

See if this compiles for you

Answer (score 7):

To store the date use this:

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDate forKey:@"myDateKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to get it use this:

```
NSDate *myDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDateKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is just a silly mistake...

You haven't assigned a date in `date1`, use

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
```

To retrieve it use,

```
NSLog(@"-> %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"myDateKey"]);
```